# An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i have global.asax file

```
  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MSOL.ERP.Services.WebApiApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

and global.asax.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using System.Web.Routing;


namespace ERPServices
 {
      public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
       {
             protected void Application_Start()
                   {
                        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                }
     }
 }
```

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type
>   'MSOL.ERP.Services.WebApiApplication'.
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

what should i do to get rid of it?

Comment: i rmoved Inherits="MSOL.ERP.Services.WebApiApplication" and problem solved

Comment: Why is there a difference between the namespace in your `asax` file (`MSOL.ERP.Services`) and the one in your code behind (`ERPServices`)? That's your problem.